# Regexp: wildcard character with exceptions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, regex, ruby

I am not very familiar with regex. I am trying to match routes in ruby. I have a situation where I have some `/route/:id` that can take the 'id' parameter. I would like to match the route to any string with parameters as long as there is no forward slash. So anything like `/route/123` should match but anything like `/route/subroute/123` should not since there is a forward slash after 'subroute'. This is my current regex pattern that matches the '/routes/' portion and allows any string to take place of the 'id' parameter: `\A\/routes\/\z*`. This works, but if a forward slash is present in the 'id' portion of the route, the match still succeeds. What can I do to allow any string as the 'id' as long as a forward slash is not present?

Comment: Maybe just `/\A\/route\/\d+\z`?

Comment: Try: `\A\/routes\/[^\/]+\/?\z`

Comment: @anubhava, that was close, but it would still allow a forward slash as long as there was nothing after it. So '/route/123/' still worked

Comment: If you don't want to allow last trailing slash then use: `\A\/route\/[^\/]+\z`

Comment: So, `/\A\/route\/\d+\z/` should work, right? No slash at the end, just one or more digits after `/route/`.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I had no luck with yours either

Comment: @rickyz: [See this demo](https://rubular.com/r/Bi6szMX41DSA1W)

Comment: @anubhava That still allows for unwanted forward slashes. I found something that worked for me though

Comment: Curious to know which input text allowed unwanted forward slash?

Comment: @anubhava Some of the examples you have in your demo are stuff that I did not want to allow. For example, '/route/subroute/123' should not work. The reason behind this is that I  will be checking any subroutes independently.

Comment: And as per that demo `/route/subroute/123` is not matching. Only highlighted text is matching/working others are not (look at the match result on right hand side)

Comment: @anubhava, I am very sorry about that. I was not familiar with the tool and did not realize that the highlighted ones meant they worked. Your answer was correct.

Answer (score 3):

This ended up being the pattern that worked for my case:
`^\/route(\/[A-Za-z0-9\-\_]*)?$`

Since it is a route, I found it better to allow only valid url characters and I use the parentheses (...)? for cases of routes that do not take parameters at all so '/route', '/route/', and '/route/abc' will all work, but '/route/abc/' will not.

Answer (score 1):

In Ruby, `^` marks the start of any line, not string, so instead of `^`, you need `\A`. Same with `$`, to match a string end position, you need to use `\z`.

Also, to match a single path subpart (the string between two slashes here) you can use a negated character class `[^\/]+` / `[^\/]*`. If you plan to restrict the chars in the subpart to alphanumeric, hyphen and underscore, you can replace `[^\/]` with `[\w-]`.

So, you can also use

```rb
/\A\/route(?:\/[\w-]*)?\z/
```

*Details*:

- `\A` - start of string
- `\/route` - a literal `/route` string
- `(?:\/[\w-]*)?` - an optional (due to the last `?`) non-capturing group that matches an optional sequence of `/` and then zero or more alphanumeric, underscore (`\w`) or hyphen chars
- `\z` - end of string.

See the [Rubular demo](https://rubular.com/r/f0NSgbgeJF8X82) (here, `^` and `$` are used for demo purposes only since the input is a single multiline text).

Comment: Thank you sir. This is definitely a cleaner solution.